# Is it possible to match the start of the remainder of a /g Javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am building a parsing state machine which uses some light regex to detect certain tokens. I want to be able to look at an arbitrary position in a large string and determine if a regex matches strictly starting at that position. The strings I am parsing may be arbitrarily large and I am potentially testing this regex against a huge number of characters, so taking a slice of the string from the position and matching a non-global regex against `^` is highly inefficient (I think?)

What I could like to be able to do is something like this:

```
var longString = 'abc123defghi45jk...';
var numberRe = /\d+/g;

numberRe.lastIndex = 3;
var match = numberRe.exec(longString);

console.log(match);
```

and have the regex match *only* when `numberRe.lastIndex` is on a substring which matches the regex, such that `numberRe.exec(longString.slice(numberRe.lastIndex))` would have the same result.

Is this possible?

Comment: If your expressions are simple you may be better off not using regular expressions at all and write your own tokenizer.

Comment: This is a minimal example

Comment: Well, recursive descent tokenizers are actually very easy to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sticky (`y`) flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky) does exactly that and recently made it into the JavaScript standard (it was originally a Mozilla extension):

```
> var digit = /\d/y;
> digit.exec('12x3')
[ '1', index: 0, input: '12x3' ]
> digit.exec('12x3')
[ '2', index: 1, input: '12x3' ]
> digit.exec('12x3')
null
```

If you’re targeting an engine without support, you can use the `index` property of the match and make sure it lines up with the previous value of the regular expression’s `lastIndex`:

```
function stickyMatch(regex, string) {
    var expectedIndex = regex.lastIndex;
    var match = regex.exec(string);

    if (!match || match.index !== expectedIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex = 0;
        return null;
    }

    return match;
}

var digit = /\d/g;

console.log(stickyMatch(digit, '12x3'));
console.log(stickyMatch(digit, '12x3'));
console.log(stickyMatch(digit, '12x3'));
```

(Slicing repeatedly likely won’t be slow on modern engines thanks to string optimizations¹, but this is nicer anyway.)

<sub>¹ *waves hands vigorously*</sub>

Comment: Brilliant. The legacy technique is still inefficient since it forces the regex to search forward through a potentially long and sparse string before coming to a negative conclusion. Thankfully I'm not very worried about old platforms.